# Chamar Form pela String

Tags: delphi

Olá, fiz uma rotina para chamar os `forms` pelo nome do Form, '`fmContas`', '`fmProdutos`', etc., depois de chamá-la elas estão com NIL, como atribuir o form padrão ao nome?

A Rotina: chamo por chama_prog('fmProdutos');

```
    procedure TfmMain.chama_prog(const Nome : AnsiString);
var
  FrmClass : TFormClass;
  Frm : TForm;
begin
  { Criar o Formulário pelo Nome }
  try
     FrmClass := TFormClass(FindClass('T'+Nome));

     if not prog_ativo(nome) then
        begin
        Frm := FrmClass.Create(nil);
        Frm.Name := nome;
        Frm.Show;
        end;
  except
    on E: EClassNotFound do
    begin
      MensGeral('Módulo não Encontrado ' +#13+ 'Possivelmente não foi Liberado.', 'E');
    end;
  end;
end;

function TfmMain.prog_ativo(nome: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount -1 do
      begin
      if Screen.Forms[i].Name = nome then
         begin
         Screen.Forms[i].BringToFront;
         Result := true;
         Exit;
         end;
      end;
end;
```

O Problema, neste exemplo, `fmProdutos`, tenho um data module, `dmProdutos` que no Evento AfterScroll queria testar se o fmProdutos está criado (not NIL).

```
procedure TdmProdutos.tbProdutosAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if fmProdutos <> nil then
   fmProdutos.edCodigo.Text := FloatToStrF(tbProdutosPRO_CODIGO.Value, ffNumber, 9, 0);
end;
```

Mas o `fmProdutos` apesar de não dar erro, sempre está NIL pois eu criei na verdade o FRM, alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Comment: Valeu Luiz, foi a primeira vez que usei o StackOverflow para perguntar

Answer (score 1):

Acabei fazendo assim, funcionou mas se alguém tiver uma solução melhor, por favor

```
for i := fmMain.MDIChildCount - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
    if fmMain.MDIChildren[i].Name = 'fmProdutos' then
       fmProdutos := TfmProdutos(fmMain.MDIChildren[i]);
    end;
```